# Given a (Python) Selenium WebElement, can I get the innerText?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

The following

```python
element = driver.execute_script("return $('.theelementclass')")[0]
```

finds me my element (a *div* that *only* contains some text), but:

```python
element.text
```

returns an empty string (which is a surprise). From the JavaScript console:

```javascript
$('.theelementclass').text  // Also (consistently) empty
$('.theelementclass').innerText  // YES! Gets the div's text.
```

Given that I have some WebElement, can I find the innerText? (For boring reasons, I want to operate with a found webelement, not the original query.)

I'm including the surrounding HTML. However, I don't think it's useful (since the element is found and is unique).

```html
<first-panel on-click="onClickLearnMore()" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="comp-onboarding-first-thought-panel">
    <div class="onboarding-text-container">
      <div class="theelementclass">
        Congratulations.
        You found the text is here!
      </div>
      <div class="button-cont">
        <div ng-click="onClickButton()">Learn more about The Thing</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</first-panel>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML you're trying to get the text from?

Comment: does it works with element.get_attribute('innerText')? you can also try with element.get_attribute('innerHTML'). what browser driver are you using (firefox, chrome, etc)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('theelementclass')
text = element.get_attribute('innerText')
```

So you can do similar stuff with '**outerHTML**', '**href**', '**src**', etc. with the **get_attribute()** method.

Comment: Bravo recommending use of the provided methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass an webelement to JavaScript code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.theelementclass')
inner_text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerText;", element)
```

Comment: Thanks me. I have never used in this way but solved my problem with a <a> tag text.

Answer (score 2):

`innerText` is specific to Internet Explorer. If you want a cross-platform field, use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].textContent", element)
```

`element` is an already obtained `WebElement`.

By the way, you said you tried this at the console:

```
$('.theelementclass').text
```

It won't work, because `.text` is a *function*. It has to be called.

Comment: I'm getting `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: attributes is not defined`

Comment: @etayluz I meant to type `arguments`, not `attributes`. It is fixed now. Thank you for the comment!