# Scraping text values using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping

For each vendor in an ERP system (total # of vendors = 800+), I am collecting its data and exporting this information as a pdf file. I used Selenium with Python, created a class called Scraper, and defined multiple functions to automate this task. The function, gather_vendors, is responsible for scraping and does this by extracting text values from tag elements.

Every vendor has a section called EFT Manager. EFT Manager has 9 rows I am extracting from:

[image]

For #2 and #3, both have string values (crossed out confidential info). But, #3 returns null. I don’t understand why #3 onward returns null when there are text values to be extracted.

[image]

The format of code for each element is the same.

[image]

I tried switching frames but that did not work. I tried to scrape from edit mode and that didn’t work as well. I was curious if anyone ever encountered a similar situation. It seems as though no matter what I do I can’t scrape certain values… I’d appreciate any advice or insight into how I should proceed.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code snippets; instead, include them inline: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Please provide (1) expected output and (2) actual output.

Comment: Try removing the wrapping `try/except` blocks. By doing that, you're catching all exceptions, which is likely hiding your problem.

Comment: @IanLesperance thanks for the tip. I will write code inline next time. The expected output is the text value. The actual output was empty, in other words, the scraper couldn't detect the xpath. I will try removing the try/except blocks. I will update you on what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what worked for me:

1. Get rid of the try/except blocks.
2. Find elements via ID's (not xpath).

That allowed me to extract text from elements I couldn't extract from before.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to use

```
find_element_by_class_name("panelList").find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
```

To collect all of the li elements. And using `li.text` to retrieve their text values. Its hard to tell what your actual output is besides you saying "returns null"

Comment: That didn't work and resulted in a lot of empty values. Strange, so I have to think of a different approach. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located`
2. Try to get textContent with javascript fo element [Given a (python) selenium WebElement can I get the innerText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204029/given-a-python-selenium-webelement-can-i-get-the-innertext?rq=1)

   element = driver.find_element_by_id('txtTemp_creditor_agent_bic')
   text= driver.execute_script("return attributes[0].textContent", element)

Comment: I tried the first suggestion but it I doesn't work. I will try the next suggestion soon and update what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the way of extracting the elements on web page to ID's, since all the the aspects have different `id` provided. If you want to use xpaths, then you should try the JavaScript function to find them.

E.g.

```
//span[text()='Bank Name']
```