# How to get the text from a webpage element using Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, text-extraction

I am trying to get a series of text from a web element, but unable to.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<span class="versionInfo">
  <span class="menu-highight">SoftFEPVis (GUI): </span> == $0
  "1.6.4"
  </span>
```

Where `SoftFEPVis (GUI):` and `1.6.4` are the texts which I would like to be able extract.

I am able to locate the element, and print out its class (menu-highlight), but un-able to extract `SoftFEPVis (GUI):` and `1.6.4`.

I tried :

```
Version_Number = Browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//[@id="versionDropDown"]/div/span[3]/span').getText()
```

and got an error:

```
'WebElement' object has no attribute getText.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .getText() you could use:

```
.get_attribute('innerText')
```

or

```
.get_attribute('innerHtml')
```

or

```
.text
```

If it helps, here is a more in-depth discussion of the topic:
[Given a (python) selenium WebElement can I get the innerText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204029/given-a-python-selenium-webelement-can-i-get-the-innertext)

Answer (score 0):

[getText()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText()) is a *Selenium Java* client method, where as from your code trials and the error message presumably you are using *Selenium Python* client.

---

### Solution

To print the text ***SoftFEPVis (GUI):*** and ***1.6.4*** you can use the [*text*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(Browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.versionInfo").text)
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(Browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='versionInfo']").text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```